# Every Normal Map Bake of Mine Has Texture Glitches

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, normal-map

Even tho I have followed like 5, 6 tutorials already the bake result does not look right.

Blend file of the mess I have...

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SQHWamrD589K07PehckcB-0ZHNSdTB4u/view?usp=sharing

And this to be honest actually seems like my best attempt at normal map baking, even tho it's still bad as hell and I have no clue at all how to fix it...

I would really, truly appreciate any help, because this is driving me crazy.

Ps - the already baked normal map texture is applied to the low poly model

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 3):

You need to unwrap the low-poly object properly. Your UV unwrap is bad because some UV faces overlap. As a result, these faces share the same spot of the image texture. This can't work.

[image: bad UV unwrap]

There is only one short seam across the face. This results in one huge UV island that has a lot of compressions/stretching. You can see this when you use a checkerboard texture. The model's face has very little detail (small squares) and the back of the head has a lot of details.
Ideally, all squares should be the same size to provide the same level of detail. The head model at the right was unwrapped with *Smart UV Project*. It creates many UV islands but the level of detail is much better.

[image: checkboard test]

A proper UV unwrap gives you a much better result. For the bake, you don't need a cage since there are actually no opposite mesh parts where overlays could occur (such as armpits or between the thighs). Just increase the *Extrusion* value a bit, like 0.2 m. This automatically creates a cage by inflating the object.

[image: baked normal map]

Guess which one is the low-poly.

> It's the right one.